# How do I know what PHP object is generated when I pass JSON to the script via $_POST?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Is there a way other than by guess-and-check?

To give a concrete example, my JSON object is

```
{'action': 'member_update', 'formStuff' : postData}
```

where `postData` is like

```
[{"name":"fullname","value":"John Skeet"},{"name":"title","value":"Stack Overflow Poster"},{"name":"bio","value":"blah blah blah "},{"name":"sord","value":"3"},{"name":"memberAction","value":"add"}]
```

and that `postData` object, whatever it turns into in PHP land, is

```
`$_POST['formStuff']`.
```

I want to know how I can get the values `"John Skeet"`, `"Stack Overflow Poster"`, etc. I've already tried, for example, both `$_POST['formStuff']['fullname']` and $`_POST['formStuff']->fullname`, neither of which work.

Oh yea, and I tested with `count($_POST['formStuff'])` that the object is of length 5, if that helps narrow it down lol

Comment: There shouldn't be any `$_POST['postData']` variable. `$_POST` should only contain the keys `'action'` and `'formStuff'`

Comment: That was a type-o by me ... Let me change.

Comment: Do you mean when JSON is being Posted to a PHP handler or when you wish to collect an element out of `$_POST`? Can you give us `var_export($_POST);` from your handler?